# why does my while loop stop after executed another query inside?closed

Tags: php, mysql

my while loop stops after executed another query inside... can you correct my codes? I want to update the column status in table ordered_items_supplier to "Pending" when the pi_number is found in the table purchased_items_supplier and if not found the column status is "Active".

```
$sql2 = "select * from ordered_items_supplier";
$result = $connect->query($sql2);
if($result->num_rows > 0){

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $pi_number = $row['pi_number'];


        $sql = "select * from purchased_items_supplier where pi_number = '$pi_number'";
        $result = $connect->query($sql);
        if($result->num_rows > 0){

            while ($row2 = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $pi_number = $row2['pi_number'];
                $sql = "update ordered_items_supplier set status = 'Pending' where pi_number = '$pi_number'";
                $query = $connect->query($sql);


            }


        }else{
                $sql = "update ordered_items_supplier set status = 'Delivered' where pi_number = '$pi_number'";
                $query = $connect->query($sql);
            }

    }



}
```

here's my mysql.. it should update the status "Delivered" in ID 11
[image]

Comment: My guess is that you're overwriting `$result` with your second query. Change the second use of `$result` to `$result2`.

Comment: You're resetting the value of `$result`, so this breaks the first while loop

Comment: ahh.. i see, thanks a lot.. it works now, sorry i'm so exhausted now. hahah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is overwriting the same variable each time.

Check that you use `$result` for the outer and inner query both.That's why the problem occur. So  don't overwriting the `$result` variable.